# Reading array element in bash not returning just string

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I'm trying to read an array from a plist and pull just the string of the array element.

This is a sample plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <array>
        <string>User;Domain;Group</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is the bash code I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
entitlements=$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.company.plist Entitlements)
for i in "${entitlements[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

When I run it, I'm given this:

```
(
    "User;Domain;Group"
)
```

Instead of:

```
"User;Domain;Group"
```

I'm running: "GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)"

Comment: Why do you think `$entitlements` is an array? You never did anythink to split it up into separate array elements.

Comment: Arrays are created with syntax like `variable=(x y z)`. You have nothing like that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither `defaults` or `PlistBuddy` can output arrays in bash-compatible formats. One possibility is to use `PlistBuddy` to get the array elements one-by-one, and use that to build the bash array:

```
#!/bin/bash
entitlements=()
i=0
while e=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :Entitlements:$i" /Library/Preferences/com.company.plist 2>/dev/null); do
    entitlements+=("$e")
    ((i++))
done
```

This is rather inefficient, since it processes the entire plist file over again for each element, but I'm assuming it's small enough that this isn't a big problem.